# How to install and run MongoDB on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, software-installation, configuration, systemctl, mongodb

I am trying to install and run a MongoDB server on CentOS 7 machine. The CentOS 7 machine is in my university campus and I am accessing it from my home over ssh through VPN.

I have followed **every** step given in the link:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/

Here is the output of `sudo systemctl start mongod` :

```
Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Here is the output of `systemctl status mongod.service` :

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-12-30 00:23:07 IST; 1min 41s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 61587 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=14)
  Process: 61584 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 61581 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 61578 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 30 00:23:07 smart systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
Dec 30 00:23:07 smart mongod[61587]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
Dec 30 00:23:07 smart mongod[61587]: forked process: 61589
Dec 30 00:23:07 smart mongod[61587]: ERROR: child process failed, exited with 14
Dec 30 00:23:07 smart mongod[61587]: To see additional information in this output, start without the "--for...tion.
Dec 30 00:23:07 smart systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=14
Dec 30 00:23:07 smart systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
Dec 30 00:23:07 smart systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Dec 30 00:23:07 smart systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Here is the output of `journalctl -xe` :

```
Dec 30 00:23:07 smart polkitd[1826]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:61557:106467206 (system bus
Dec 30 00:23:08 smart dbus[1879]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.fedoraproject.Setroubleshootd'
Dec 30 00:23:08 smart setroubleshoot[61594]: failed to retrieve rpm info for /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fastopen
Dec 30 00:23:08 smart setroubleshoot[61594]: SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/mongod from open access on the file /pr
Dec 30 00:23:08 smart python[61594]: SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/mongod from open access on the file /proc/sys/n

                                     *****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

                                     If you believe that mongod should be allowed open access on the tcp_fastopen f
                                     Then you should report this as a bug.
                                     You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
                                     Do
                                     allow this access for now by executing:
                                     # ausearch -c 'mongod' --raw | audit2allow -M my-mongod
                                     # semodule -i my-mongod.pp

Dec 30 00:23:11 smart setroubleshoot[61594]: SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/mongod from unlink access on the sock_f
Dec 30 00:23:11 smart python[61594]: SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/mongod from unlink access on the sock_file mong

                                     *****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

                                     If you believe that mongod should be allowed unlink access on the mongodb-2701
                                     Then you should report this as a bug.
                                     You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
                                     Do
                                     allow this access for now by executing:
                                     # ausearch -c 'mongod' --raw | audit2allow -M my-mongod
                                     # semodule -i my-mongod.pp

Dec 30 00:24:52 smart chronyd[2023]: Source 162.159.200.123 replaced with 5.189.141.35
```

I don't know where I went wrong or I missed some fundamental configuration step.
I have tried many online blogs/sites like:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/568238/372656
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64818226
but they didn't help.

Can anyone please explain me how can I resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: it says right there in your journalctl output: SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/mongod from open access on the file /proc/sys/n... SELinux is stopping mongod from working. You need to modify SELinux to allow mongo db to run, or put SELinux in permissive mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose I should have put my comment as a solution:

It says in the journalctl output that SELinux is preventing Mongod from open access on some file, which is stopping mongodb from working. You need to put SELinux in permissive mode, or tell SELinux to allow mongodb to run:

See [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/770227/selinux-setup-for-mongodb) for more details. [This link](https://developpaper.com/detailed-explanation-of-the-problem-of-selinux-blocking-mongodb-startup-under-centos-7-system/) for a longer explination, or just set enforcing=0 as per link 1, or edit /etc/selinux/config and set it to permissive.

Comment: Thanks @number9